# c++ While loops prints the couts twice

Tags: c++, while-loop

In my code, the while loop prints the cout twice when it should print it once, as well as the function's couts. I don't understand why it's doing this - it is supposed to display

> What would you like to do?
>
> Deposit
>
> Withdraw
>
> Cancel

But, it displays that twice.

```
while (yesNo == 'Y') {

        cout << "What would you like to do?"
            << endl
            << endl;

        menu();
        getline(cin, bankChoice);

        if (bankChoice == "Withdraw")
        {

            withdrawTotal = withdraw(bankAmount);
            bankAmount = withdrawTotal;
            cout << "You now have $"
                << bankAmount
                << " in your account."
                << endl;

            cout << "Would you like to do anything else?"
                << endl
                << "Y/N: ";
            cin >> yesNo;

        }

        if (bankChoice == "Deposit")
        {

            depositTotal = deposit(bankAmount);
            bankAmount = depositTotal;
            cout << "You now have $"
                << bankAmount
                << " in your account."
                << endl;

            cout << "Would you like to do anything else?"
                << endl
                << "Y/N: ";
            cin >> yesNo;
        }


        if (bankChoice == "Cancel") {
            return 0;
        }

    }
```

That is the loop I am using. If additional code is needed I can post it as well, but this is the part that is causing the issue. I've tried the code without it and it works fine, but I'd like to get the code to loop until the user enters 'N'.

Comment: What does `menu()` do?

Comment: To understand what is happening, output the result of the `cin>>`  (as int)

Comment: @AndrewCheong 'menu()' just displays Deposit, Withdraw, and Cancel

Comment: Could get line be replaced with cin? It might be that a stored character is causing an automatic advancement.  Try clearing out the input buffer after each input.

Comment: Please work a little more on a [mcve]. You are showing a lot of unrelated code, and you are not showing the `menu()` function which is exactly where the error occurs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using both `std::getline` and `operator>>` to read from `std::cin`. `operator>>` does not consume the trailing newline, so the next call to `std::getline`() will immediately read the following newline and interpret it as an empty line of text that was entered. This will run through the loop, and go back up to the top, for the second prompt.

Never use `operator>>` with `std::cin` when you intend to read a single line of text.

The following short example demonstrates this point:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    char c;
    std::string l;

    std::cin >> c;

    std::cout << "A line of text please: ";

    std::getline(std::cin, l);
}
```

Run it, enter "Y", and try to figure it out, yourself, why the program terminates immediately.

Once again: don't use `operator>>` to read lines of text from `std::cin`. It is a recipe for grief, and bugs.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Sam's answer, I'd like to recommend that you extract common functionality outside your two if statements:

```
std::string yesNo;

while (yesNo.compare("Y") == 0) {
    cout << "What would you like to do?"
        << endl
        << endl;

    menu();
    getline(cin, bankChoice);

    if (bankChoice == "Cancel")
        return 0;

    if (bankChoice == "Withdraw") {
        withdrawTotal = withdraw(bankAmount);
        bankAmount = withdrawTotal;
    }

    if (bankChoice == "Deposit") {
        depositTotal = deposit(bankAmount);
        bankAmount = depositTotal;
    }

    cout << "You now have $"
        << bankAmount
        << " in your account."
        << endl;

    cout << "Would you like to do anything else?"
        << endl
        << "Y/N: ";

    std::getline(std::cin, yesNo);
}
```